# How to redirect cmd output to file with same name as input file?

Tags: cmd, window, output

I am redirecting output to file:

```
read.exe 1000318.simb > 1000318.txt
```

but i would like to set name of the output file dynamically:

```
read.exe 1000318.simb > [auto].txt
```

Where [auto] is same name as of input file without sufix (1000318). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a batch file with any name containing:

```
@echo off
if not "%~1" == "" read.exe "%~1" >"%~dpn1.txt"
```

Or with a single command line in batch file:

```
@if not "%~1" == "" read.exe "%~1" >"%~dpn1.txt"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~1` (first argument without surrounding double quotes) and `%~dpn1` (drive, path and file name without file extension of first argument).
- `echo /?`
- `if /?`